# delete action is not working after adding extra code inside it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, onclick, action

I have delete action in my controller, this is the code in pickups_controller.rb

```
  def delete
    @pickup = Pickup.find(params[:id])
    if !@pickup.nil?
      @pickup.destroy
      render json: { success_message: "Success!, Pickup is deleted." }, status: :ok
    end
  end
```

I call the delete action using javascript json by pressing a button using assets/javascripts/pickups.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {



    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // delete the pickup you choose

    $('.removepickup.btn.btn-primary').on('click', function() {
        var pickup_div = $(this).parents('.removepickupparent');
        var pickup_id = pickup_div.attr('id');
        var x = "../deletepickup?id=" + pickup_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: x,
            success: function(data) {
                var success = data.success_message;
                $(".successr"+ pickup_id).text(success).show(0).delay(1000).hide(0);   
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload();
                }, 1000);
            },

            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                if(xhr.status==404) {
                    $(".errorl"+ pickup_id).text("Fail!, pickup Is Already Deleted Before").show(0).delay(1000).hide(0);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                         location.reload();
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }

        });
    });



    // when pressing on this button, it redirects you to create pickup page

    $('.addpickup.btn.btn-primary').on('click', function() {
        var success = "Redirecting to add pickup Page"
        $(".successp").text(success).show(0).delay(2000).hide(0);
        setTimeout(function () {
        $(location).attr('href', '../createpickup');
        }, 2000);

    });


});
```

the function is working great, but when adding 4 lines extra code inside the delete action, it doesn't work, here's the code after adding 4 lines of extra code inside my delete action, and the action is not working.

```
  def delete
    @pickup = Pickup.find(params[:id])
    if !@pickup.nil?

      # the start of the extra code
      @trip = Trip.find(@pickup.trip_id)
      if !@trip.nil?
        @trip.seatsno = @trip.seatsno + 1
        @trip.save
      end
      # the end of the extra code

      @pickup.destroy
      render json: { success_message: "Success!, Pickup is deleted." }, status: :ok
    end
  end
```

any solutions please? .. knowing that I'm still beginner in Ruby on Rails

Note:

I used byebug, and when reaching the first line in the etra code I got this error in the local server terminal 
`"request.env["action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"] ||= show_detailed_exceptions?"`

Comment: So is there an error message?

Comment: I used byebug, and when reaching the first line in the etra code I got this error in the local server terminal "request.env["action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"] ||= show_detailed_exceptions?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `find_by` instead of the `find` method. The `find' method raises the exception if a particular record is not found, while`find_by` returns nil.

Usage:

```
find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Comment: thanks, that really was enough and solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is more of a refactor suggestion than the actual answer, but it may fix your problem as well.

You can refactor your action to this:

```
def delete
  @pickup = Pickup.find(params[:id])
  # no need to test @pickup.nil? here because `find` method raise 
  # an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error if the record is not found
  # which should be caught by ApplicationController to render a 404
  if @pickup.destroy
    @pickup.trip.update_attributes(seatsno: @pickup.trip.seatsno + 1)
    render json: { success_message: "Success!, Pickup is deleted." }, status: :ok
  else
    render json: { error_message: "Error, Pickup could not be deleted." }, status: 409
  end
end
```

---

Even better, move the concern of incrementing `seatsno` to the `Pickup` model:

```
# app/models/pickup.rb
after_destroy :increment_trip_seatsno

def increment_trip_seatsno
  self.trip.update_attributes(seatsno: self.trip.seatsno + 1)
end
```

And remove the concern from the Controller. This way, every time a `Pickup` record is destroyed via Rails (console or other places in your app), the trip will be updated accordingly.